# Batch script to delete a registry and run a file

Tags: batch-file, registry

i'm trying to make a batch script that will automatically delete a registry entry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\mIRC\LastRun) and run a file, how can I start about this?

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off &setlocal
reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\mIRC\LastRun" /f
start "" /b "run a file"
```